# Setting HyperLink value for last item in GridView

Tags: c#, gridview, hyperlink

I have a GridView basket (called BasketGrid) which contains a listing of products selected by the user for purchase. I am trying to create a HyperLink called, "Edit Options" that will allow the user to return to the product page to edit the item options if they need to. What I have is mostly working but the last item in the GridView's "Edit Options" link is never set, regardless of what the last item in the basket. Other than this issue, the function appears to be working the way I want it to. What am I missing?

This is the function that is setting the "Edit Options" HyperLink:

```
protected string BuildLink (object dataItem)
    {
        string ProductLink = "";
        int rowIndex = 0;
        foreach (GridViewRow basketRow in BasketGrid.Rows)
        {
            int basketItemId = (int)BasketGrid.DataKeys[rowIndex].Value;
            int itemIndex = _Basket.Items.IndexOf(basketItemId);
            if ((itemIndex > -1))
            {
                BasketItem item = _Basket.Items[itemIndex];
                if ((item.OrderItemType == OrderItemType.Product))
                {
                    HyperLink optionsLink = (HyperLink)basketRow.FindControl("EditProdOpts");
                    if (optionsLink != null)
                    {
                        optionsLink.NavigateUrl = string.Format("~/Admin/orders/Create/CreateOrderAddProduct.aspx?Action=Edit&UID={0}&LineID={1}&ProdId={2}", _UserId, item.BasketItemId, item.ProductId);
                    }
                }
                rowIndex++;
            }  
        }
        return ProductLink;
    }
```

This is the row in the GridView that contains the "Edit Options" HyperLink:

```
 <ItemTemplate>
      <uc:BasketItemDetail ID="BasketItemDetail1" runat="server" BasketItem="<%# Container.DataItem %>" LinkProducts="false" /><br />
       <asp:PlaceHolder ID="EditOptPanel" runat="server" Visible='<%# ShowOptionsLink(Container.DataItem) %>'>
           <asp:HyperLink ID="EditProdOpts" runat="server" Text="Edit Options" NavigateUrl='<%# BuildLink(Container.DataItem) %>' />
        </asp:PlaceHolder>
  </ItemTemplate>
```

Comment: just some questions: why are you not updating the "ProductLink" variable? why the rowIndex variable is incremented only inside the nested if?

Comment: Ah, now I see my mistake. I wasn't setting the ProductLink variable like I should have. Thanks for pointing that out--I honestly was totally oblivious for a while there.

Comment: i'll post the answer then =)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this comment made the OP solve his problem, he was not actually setting the ProductLink variable

> just some questions: why are you not updating the "ProductLink" variable? why the rowIndex variable is incremented only inside the nested if?

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: @Р̀СТȢѸ́ФХѾЦЧШЩЪЫЬѢѤЮѦѪѨѬѠѺѮѰѲѴ thanks, i'll edit the answer, i just copied the comment that made him solve the problem, i'll add explanation.